# Load balancer error with Nginx and Docker

Tags: docker, http, nginx, flask, load-balancing

I'm trying to setup a load balancer with 3 replicas to handle queries.
I'm using Nginx for load balancer, Flask to deploy an API and Postgres to handle data in a replicative schhema.

My Docker-Compose looks like this:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  tienda:
    build: ./api
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
    depends_on:
      - postgresql-master
      - postgresql-slave
    ports:
      - 8080
  postgresql-master:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - 'postgresql_master_data:/bitnami/postgresql'
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_MODE=master
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_USER=repl_user
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD=repl_password
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=postgres
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=123
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=tienda
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  postgresql-slave:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    depends_on:
      - postgresql-master
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_MODE=slave
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_USER=repl_user
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD=repl_password
      - POSTGRESQL_MASTER_HOST=postgresql-master
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=123
      - POSTGRESQL_MASTER_PORT_NUMBER=5432
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:    
      - tienda
volumes:
  postgresql_master_data:
    driver: local
```

and nginx.conf looks like this:

```
upstream loadbalancer {
    server sist3-tienda-1:3050 weight=3 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=5s;
    server sist3-tienda-2:3050 weight=2 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=5s;
    server sist3-tienda-3:3050 weight=1 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=5s;
}
server {
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
    proxy_read_timeout 5m;
}}
```

Problem begins when I try to GET `http://localhost:8080` I get 502 Bad Gateway and Docker-compose shows:

```
nginx_1              | 2021/12/06 06:06:23 [error] 31#31: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.21.0.4:3050/", host: "localhost:8080"
nginx_1              | 2021/12/06 06:06:23 [warn] 31#31: *2 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.21.0.4:3050/", host: "localhost:8080"
nginx_1              | 2021/12/06 06:06:23 [error] 31#31: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.21.0.6:3050/", host: "localhost:8080"
nginx_1              | 2021/12/06 06:06:23 [warn] 31#31: *2 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.21.0.6:3050/", host: "localhost:8080"
nginx_1              | 2021/12/06 06:06:23 [error] 31#31: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.21.0.5:3050/", host: "localhost:8080"
nginx_1              | 2021/12/06 06:06:23 [warn] 31#31: *2 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.21.0.5:3050/", host: "localhost:8080"
nginx_1              | 172.21.0.1 - - [06/Dec/2021:06:06:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4" "-"
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are the IP addresses correct? `172.21.0.1` and `172.17.0.1`

Comment: what is running on `172.17.0.1:3050`? (now `sist3-tienda-1:3050`)

Comment: @Raptor updated, it was a try to fix :P

Comment: Can you telnet to the IP and port specified?

Comment: @Raptor If I get into container that runs Nginx and Telnet to 127.0.0.1 3050 (where flask shows that endpoint are listening) I get: ```Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused```. Same if I try to telnet outside from containers

Comment: Might seem to obvious and therefor incorect, but aren't you suppose to open port 3050 on your "tienda" instances? Currently you have your LB directing to port 3050 but the compose file only has either 8080 or 80 open.